# Remove copywrite symbols (Special Characters) from CSV file using PHP or Bash

Tags: php, bash, csv, sed

I have a CSV file with thousands of product description with either ® or ™ in the title.

This is causing my importer to stop reading the line when it reaches these symbols.

I need to remove them or change them to (TM), (R) etc.

I have the following PHP file which replaces text but doesnt work for the symbols:

```
$fname = "/../var/www/vhosts/website.co.uk/httpdocs/folder/file.csv";
$fhandle = fopen($fname,"r");
$content = fread($fhandle,filesize($fname));

$content = str_replace("red", "yellow", $content); --------//This works!
$content = str_replace("®", "r", $content);        -------//This doesnt!

$fhandle = fopen($fname,"w");
fwrite($fhandle,$content);
fclose($fhandle);
```

I have used sed but with no luck.

```
sed 's/[™®]//g' /../var/www/vhosts/website.co.uk/httpdocs/folder/file.csv > /../var/www/vhosts/website.co.uk/httpdocs/folder/file.csv
```

Comment: Tried it, Just outputs a blank csv file

Comment: `perl -pe 's/®/(r)/g' < your.csv` seems to work for me. If it does not, maybe some charset/encoding problem? Another thought, you could try [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) in PHP on your data and see whether it recognizes the symbols.

Comment: Adding the -C7 parameter for Perl forces it to use UTF-8 on STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR, as in `perl -C7 -pe 's/®/(r)/g' < your.csv`. The PHP approach works for me as well, it gives you something like `abc&reg;def&trade;ghi` (which can be used in another substitution then).

Comment: Hmm not sure why it isnt working as its not throwing up any errors. How would I use htmlentities() within my php script above?

Comment: Instead of the str_replace(). You would use `$content = htmentities($content);`.